# Error message: ! Use of \bbm does not match its definition

Tags: macros, errors

I have the following minimal working example -- why does `\def\bbm15` not work?? The error I get is

```
*File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
! Use of \bbm doesn't match its definition.
l.16 \bbm1
          5 %this generates an error!
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.16 \bbm1
          5 %this generates an error!
End of file on the terminal!*
```

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}

\def\bbm15{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\begin{bmatrix}}
\def\bbm20{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}\begin{bmatrix}}
\def\ebm{\end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}    
X = 
%\bbm20 %this works fine!    
%\bbm15 %this generates an error!    
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\begin{bmatrix} %this works fine!    
X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1p} \\    
X_{21} & X_{22} & \cdots & X_{2p} \\    
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \cdots \\    
X_{n1} & X_{n2} & \cdots & X_{np}     
\ebm     
.    
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! LaTeX and TeX command names should not include both letters and numbers.

Answer (score 7):

`\def\bbm15{..}`

defines `\bbm` such that it must be followed by `15`

`\def\bbm20{..}`

redefines `\bbm` so that it must be followed by `20`

so after this definition `\bm15` will give the error shown in the question.

If you use `\newcommand` you will be warned of redefinitions

```
\newcommand\bbmA{\arraystretch}{1.5}\begin{bmatrix}}
\newcommand\bbmB{\arraystretch}{2.0}\begin{bmatrix}}
```

then you can use `\bbmA` and `\bbmB` but probably I would suggest

```
\newcommand\bbm[1][1.5]{\arraystretch}{#1}\begin{bmatrix}}
```

and use `\bbm` and `\bbm[2]`

Answer (score 5):

The reason why `\bbm20` appears to "work fine", as you put it, whereas `\bbm15` does not, is coincidence; David's answer provides a more thorough explanation. For sure, if you *reverse* the ordering of the two `\def` instructions, i.e., if you define `\bbm20` before rather than after `\bbm15`, you'll find that `\bbm20` throws an error whereas `\bbm15` now "works fine". (If you had used `\newcommand` instead of `\def` to create the macros `\bbm15` and `\bbm20`, you would have received some useful messages alerting you to the syntax error issue.)

What's going on? In general, names of TeX and LaTeX macros must consist either of uppercase and lowercase letters (A to Z and a to z, no other character types allowed) or a *single non-letter character*. Thus, the macro names `\bbm20` and `bbm15` simply aren't valid, from a syntactic point of view, for use in a LaTeX document.

If you must create separate macro names, I would like to suggest you use `\bbmXX` and `bbmXVX`, i.e., employ uppercase Roman "numbers" instead of arabic numerals.